# Can named semaphore be created when /dev/shm is mounted with nodev

Tags: c, linux, semaphore, mount

We are creating a named semaphore using "sem_open" linux API. Named semaphores are created in /dev/shm/ path. If /dev/shm is mounted with "nodev" option, Will be the named semaphore be created?

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't. Try it!

Comment: I tried remounting it with "mount -t tmpfs -o remount,nodev /dev/shm". But i could still see named semaphores are getting created. So what is actually blocked when we remount the /dev/shm with nodev.

Comment: in a nodev mounted filesystem contained device nodes are not interpreted as devices. That's all. So if you do a `mknod` to create a device in /dev/shm that path to the device will not work.